# type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I use a dynamic database class I constructed for all my projects. Just started with a new one, and the class is giving me a hiccup. This is my code, not the details.  But I recreated the error through minimal code.

```
function vref($arr) {
  if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) {//Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    return $refs;
  }
  return $arr;
}

$bind = 's,i,i,i,i, i,s,s,s,s, i,s,s';
$reward = ( $data['reward'] ) ? $data['reward'] : '0';
$special = '0';
$icon = '0';
$mastery = ( @$data['mastery'] ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
$added = time();
settype($added, 'string')
$arr = array(
        $bind,
        $data['name'],
        intval($data['cost']),
        intval($data['per']),
        intval($data['serv']),
        intval($data['earns']),
        intval($data['cp']),
        $data['cookTime'],
        $reward,
        $special,
        $icon,
        intval($data['type']),
        $mastery,
        $added );

$db = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $db2->prepare('INSERT INTO recipe2 (
     `name`,cost,perserv,servings,earns,
     cp,cooktime,`unlock`,special,icon,
     `type`,options,added) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?) ');
call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_param' ), vref($arr) );

// var_dump($arr)
array(14) {
[0]=> string(25) "s,i,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,s,s"
[1]=> string(18) "Bacon Cheeseburger"
[2]=> int(15)
[3]=> int(4)
[4]=> int(13)
[5]=> int(56)
[6]=> int(6)
[7]=> string(2) "5m"
[8]=> string(1) "0"
[9]=> string(1) "0"
[10]=>int(0)
[11]=>int(0)
[12]=>string(2) "No"
[13]=>string(10) "1325300795"
}

// Database Column listing
name        varchar(255)            
cost        int(10)
perserv     int(5)
servings    int(10)
earns       int(10)
cp      int(10)
cooktime    varchar(11)
unlock      varchar(255)
special     varchar(255)
icon        varchar(255)
type        int(5)
options     varchar(255)
added       varchar(12)
```

Error: **Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables**

And before anyone just simply says, count your variables. I have. Probably over 50 times now. No joke. Before an hour ago, I started using the variables, instead of direct data being put into that. vref() simply passes all the items in the array as reference variables. I have since learned that references are not to be taken lightly. Heh. But I still can't figure this out, and its frusterating.

I have 13 columns. 14 parameters being passed into bind_param().

Comment: Can you post your `vref` function?

Comment: A `var_dump($data)` would help. One thing that jumps out is you have $data['cost'] lined up as an int, are you sure it's not formatted, causing it to be a string?

Comment: You have 14 elements in your `$arr` variable when there should only be 13.

Comment: @zzatkin: The first one is the format string for the [`mysqli-stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function

Comment: @zzatkin, he is using `$arr` as the arguments to `bind_param`. The first argument is the list of types (`$bind`), and the rest of the arguments are the variables. Type string + 13 variables = 14 arguments.

Comment: @LoganSerman
`function vref($arr) {
 if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) {//Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
  $refs = array();
  foreach($arr as $key => $value) $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
  return $refs;
  }
 return $arr;
 }`

@DigitalPrecision $data is the $_FORM data. Think I need to convert those to int? I use this piece of code in my other projects and I haven't needed to do that before.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I'm hoping the error isn't just because you are using `$db = new mysqli();` but `$stmt = $db2->prepare();` (notice the difference: `$db` vs `$db2`). Typo?

Comment: @Logan Whoops. Typo on my part. That would be a undefined fatal error. Quite different.

Comment: @TonyArnold: Can you evaluate `vref($arr)` separately and tell us what its size is (or even better, a var_dump). Also, can you include the `vref` definition in your code snippet?

Comment: @TonyArnold I agree with Niklas, if you provide a dump of the array that `vref($arr)` returns, it will be easy to see where you error lies (I think).

Comment: niklas & Logan Updated above with var_dump(). Gotta add some intval()'s and see where that takes me. ( just annoyed this hasn't popped up before as an error as I've used this script for half a year without any issues before now )

Comment: @TonyArnold: May well be Digital is right with his guess.

Comment: @Niklas Updated above with intval()'s, and new var_dumb(). No change in the error. Is anyone seeing anything Im not? =(

Comment: Please don't answer for me. Its kinda my last call to see if it works for me. And your answer isn't for me. My DB column is a VARCHAR for the last column. I updated the code to make the $added a string. NO CHANGE IN ERROR....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple mistake... Ugh. I hate that. [Not my credit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686518/why-is-mysqli-statements-bind-param-giving-this-error)

```
$bind = 'siiiiissssiss'; // No commas
```

Comment: +1 for giving credit where credit was due. I found this through a Google search and wouldn't have got the answer unless you posted it. Cheers!

Comment: It would be nice is the php.net documentation had a multiple param example, I too was stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

Given your `var_dump($arr)`:

```
[0]=> string(25) "s,i,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,s,s"
[1]=> string(18) "Bacon Cheeseburger"
[2]=> int(15)
[3]=> int(4)
[4]=> int(13)
[5]=> int(56)
[6]=> int(6)
[7]=> string(2) "5m"
[8]=> string(1) "0"
[9]=> string(1) "0"
[10]=>int(0)
[11]=>int(0)
[12]=>string(2) "No"
[13]=>int(1325298618)
```

It seems to be like your `$bind` variable needs to be:

```
$bind = 's,i,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,i,i,s,i';
```

instead of

```
$bind = 's,i,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,s,s';
```

Comment: I updated the main question... I do this with the database on purpose, as the INT type in the MySQL DB lowers the number due to my computer being a 32bit system and the test system. So I by pass this making it  a string instead. Also I changed the type, and NO DIFFERENCE.

Comment: I'm not sure what your database has to do with it. The fact is that the format string given to `bind_param` must match the variables being passed to it. So `$bind`, your format string, needs to matchup with your `vardump(vref($arr))`, which, even in your updated question, is not the case.

Comment: Fixed here. Not elsewhere. And it doesn't matter what it says here. The binds match up on my end. I am going to rewrite this. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: $bind = 'siiiiissssiss'; -- No comments. Such a simple mistake. ugh