# Why is MySQLi statements bind_param giving this error?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Getting an error with my code found [HERE](http://i18.photobucket.com/albums/b142/samishi/error.jpg)... Which is a culmination of all the chatter from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685586/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-mysqli-chunk-of-code) which was "Answered" but did **not** fix my error. ($data is html form data) I have even gone out of my way to line up each variable, ?, DB column, and bind character in the hopes that it'll be a little more clearer. I've went through and made sure that all the variables match up to string / int to match up with the database ( which is another error completely, but was brought up in the other thread ).

```
    DATABASE TABLE
    name        varchar(255)            
    cost        int(10)         
    perserv     int(5)          
    servings    int(10)         
    earns       int(10)         
    cp          int(10)         
    cooktime    varchar(11)         
    unlock      varchar(255)            
    special     varchar(255)            
    icon        varchar(255)            
    type        int(5)          
    options     varchar(255)            
    added       varchar(12)
```

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: He *did* give the disclaimer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the commas in your `$bind` variable.

```
$bind = 'siiiiissssiss';
```

Comment: ... I hate when I miss something so simple... Thanks.